# How to redirect on a specific route after login?

Tags: angular, forms, spring-boot

I have to develop a form using Angular 8 and Spring Boot. I am newer on these technologies and I need some help please.

When the form is submitted, it must be analysed by an architect. If the architect validates the form, the status of the form is updated. I have already develop the front (the form) and the Rest API with Spring Boot. Now I have two problems:

1/ The architects have their own interface and the final users have their own interface too. The entreprise where I am use guardian idm as authentication system. After login, the app must know if the current user is an architect or a normal user.

Have you some idea of how to integrate this guardian idm server in this Angular/Spring Boot app and how to do the redirection ?

2/ I don't know how to change the status of a submitted form with Angular and Spring Boot. When I say "status of the form" I mean "validated" or "no validated" or "in progress of validation". The user who has submitted the form must see the steps of his submission.

I did some research but I didn't see nothing. Please, can you help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: From what I understand from the question. I think you'll need Route Guards. You can implement a Route Guard that checks the role of the user(architect or normal user) and then based on that, this guard can redirect the user to an appropriate route. Since Route guards are services, you can inject some sort of a user service in it that has a method to determine the type of the logged in user. This is all I can suggest without having a look at some code.

Comment: Thanks @SiddAjmera. I will do reseach about Route Guards. For the status, you don't have idea on what I will need?

Comment: Can you please provide your code, what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Route Guards to fulfil your requirements. Below is little bit on that.

```
Angular’s route guards are interfaces which can tell the router whether or not it should allow navigation to a requested route. They make this decision by looking for a true or false return value from a class which implements the given guard interface.
```

You can find more information on below awesome article.
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: Thanks @Arosha. And, for the status, you don't know how can I do?